# Why are white spaces in a string trimmed in shell when it is assigned to a variable?

Tags: shell, ksh

I'm assigning a string (`my    name   is     xxxxxx  ssddd`) a shell variable(`str`)
when echo the variable.

```
echo $str  
my name is xxxxxx ssddd
```

Why white spaces are not taken in to account?

Comment: How exactly do you assign? Wrapping the string in quotes should work.

Comment: It might have something to do with the "Internal Field Separator" character, which is defined in `$IFS`. [Read the KSH documentation](http://www.kornshell.com/doc/).

Comment: i'm assigning it with the quotes only `str="my name   is   xxxxxx  ssddd"` like this

Comment: I think bash interpreter is replacing white spaces, tabs with single space.

Comment: `echo "$str"`, not `echo $str`

Comment: @VikramDattu, not exactly -- bash is generating a list of arguments for `echo`, and that list of arguments puts `my`, `name`, `is`, etc. each as its own element. It's `echo` that puts a space between each of those elements.

Comment: If I might suggest a reference: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote your strings in order to preserve white space:

```
a="four    spaces"
echo $a
four spaces


echo "$a"
four    spaces
```

However, when assigning one variable to another, whitespace also is preserved:

```
a=$b
echo "$b"
four    spaces
```